# Famo.us Rotation in Physics

Tags: javascript, physics, famo.us

I'm experimenting with the Famo.us physics engine. I've done a few simple things such as bounce balls around, and attach two objects together using a spring and drag one of them around. In all of my experiments I've noticed that objects don't rotate. If you have a rectangular body and you apply a gravitational or spring force to it, it will stay perfectly upright. Is this just a limitation of the engine? Or perhaps a limitation of my knowledge.

Also, is there a better documentation than https://famo.us/docs/?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the physics engine does not support rigid body torque. There have been demos built that implement torque

http://demo.famo.us/torque/

The physics engine is also being rebuilt. Hopefully the next iteration will include torque.